# Android studio web view API33 not working properly

Tags: android

I currently migrated my application from API 26 to API 33, but the problem is.. the WebView displayed **blank**, in previous API looks normal.

Below is code of **AndroidManifest.xml** permission list :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Here's the **import** code on MainActivity :

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.File;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

 import static 
 id.ztha.elmusman12.elmulite.DetectConnection.isNetworkStatusAvialable;
```

**P.S : The "ConnectivityManager" and "NetworkInfo" color is gray in the Android Studio**

Below is the result when running on Emulator :

[image]

Comment: Add some more code that's get more idea about this .
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` add in  of application tag inside of `AndroidManifest.xml file `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code inside of `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` File

```
<application
    .....
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     
</application>
```