# Flutter/Dart app connects to server in emulator, but not when running on a device as an APK

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, apk

I have an app built using Flutter and Dart and Android Studio.

The app communicates with two servers.

Server One handles login information. When users enter their username and password into the app, it is sent to Server One and it checks if they match a record on the server.

Server Two handles user data, saving some data on the server and presenting it to the user through the GUI.

When I run the app in my emulator in Android Studio, I am able to successfully communicate with both servers. However, I run into issues when I try to run the app as an APK on my android device.

When I use the debug APK, I am able to successfully log into the app (i.e., successfully communicating with Server One). However, I cannot do this with the release APK.

With either type of APK (i.e., debug or release), I cannot communicate with Server Two (i.e., cannot see visualizations of user data).

How can I make it so that the APK runs the same as the emulated version of the app?

My Android Manifests do have Internet permissions, so that's not the problem. I also have the app environments pointing towards the correct URLs for Server One and Server Two.

I am using Flutter 3.9.0-1.0.pre.2.

It would be very helpful if someone could point me in the right direction. I can add additional information as needed. I'm not sure what pieces of code (if any) would be relevant to my question.

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75751918/android-studio-web-view-api33-not-working-properly/75752106#75752106

Answer (score 2):

You must grant Internet access in the AndroidManifest.xml file, so the app will be able to connect on physical devices too.

Go to `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
and add the next line at the same level of <application...>

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

This grant access to internet to your app.
Your AndroidManifest.xml file must look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.leflaner_empresa_frontend">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

   <application
   //.... a lot of additional settings.
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Notice that there are three AndroidManifest.xml files.

The files:
`/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and
`/android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml`
had internet privileges access granted by default,

But in the next one you must add it manually:
`/android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml`

Check it again and I hope it fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is already enabled. This is why I can communicate with Server One when using the APK.

Comment: I edited my answer, check it again and I hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks for doing that.

I followed your directions and I'm still having the same problem.

I wonder if it has to do with my AndroidManifest in src/main. When I open it, there are several errors being highlighted but I had no idea how to fix them.

Comment: It could be the reason, may be you can send a copy of your .../src/main/... file, for I check it, I may found something that can help you.